# python character decoding exception in runtime but not eclipse

Tags: python, bash, encoding

I have a python script that fetches a url page and then html escapes it.

The target page contains both english and hebrew fonts.

```
opener = urllib2.build_opener(
            urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler(),
            urllib2.HTTPHandler(debuglevel = 0),
            urllib2.HTTPSHandler(debuglevel = 0),
            urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(self.cj)
        )
response = opener.open(url)
data = response.read()
goodData = HTMLParser.HTMLParser().unescape(data)
print goodData
```

When run in eclipse the code works fine.
When packaged and the run on linux shell (ubuntu 12.04) it fails on the next to last line (right before the print) with:

```
'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 775: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I cannot debug this, since in eclipse this seems to work fine.
How come?

Comment: btw, I did make sure to add export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
to my .bashrc

Comment: Did you source the file? `echo $LC_ALL $LANG $LANGUAGE` to confirm the settings are in effect.

Comment: yep.  I did. Also, printing hebrew unicode from python into shell displays hebrew fonts correctly.
Besides, it fails before the print...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Solved it:

```
opener = urllib2.build_opener(
            urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler(),
            urllib2.HTTPHandler(debuglevel = 0),
            urllib2.HTTPSHandler(debuglevel = 0),
            urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(self.cj)
        )
response = opener.open(url)
data = response.read()
data = data.decode('utf8')
goodData = HTMLParser.HTMLParser().unescape(data)
print goodData
```

Thanks to:
[UnicodeDecodeError while processing filenames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12626019/unicodedecodeerror-while-processing-filenames)